# Can .htaccess be changed through FTP after it was edited in WordPress in a way that breaks the site?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, ftp

I made the mistake of putting in the following code on my *.htaccess* file thru Yoast SEO:

```
# Remove www from any URLs that have them:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now there's an infinite loop and I can't access my WordPress dashboard anymore. Is it possible to access the *.htaccess* file thru an FTP client like FileZilla and remove the change?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. Your .htaccess file is located in the root directory of the website and can be accessed via FTP.

Comment: Depending on your FTP client, you may need to configure it to show hidden files for .htaccess to be visible.